# Azure event grid api version undefined

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I created an azure event Topic and added an azure function (event trigger type) as a subscription. when trying to send a request through postman I get undefined API version.

Error:

{
"error": {
"code": "ApiVersionUnspecified",
"message": "An API version is required, but was not specified."
}
}

Comment: Try the following - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/post-to-custom-topic#endpoint

Comment: thanks for your answer. Now I get method not allowed error and when I try it with azure SDK it gives me cors policy error even though I made the network on the event grid public. any idea?

Answer (score 2):

This is the error you get:

[image]

As Roman Kiss says, you should use URI like below:

`https://<topic-endpoint>?api-version=2018-01-01`

(And also you need to authorize it.)

Answer (score 1):

I received this error when I was submitting a `GET` request instead of a `POST` request.

Comment: Thanks, `GET` works on localhost but when sending to Azure, `POST` is required to work